# Как сделать в Visual Studio Code вертикальные пунктирные линии для отступов кода?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Как сделать в Visual Studio Code вертикальные пунктирные линии для отступов кода (как в редакторе Visual Studio), а не просто прямые линии?

- Visual Studio
  [image: Visual Studio]
- Visual Studio Code
  [image: Visual Studio Code]

Comment: Гуглеж подсказывает, что можно подложить кастомный CSS: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/123981